# How to solve linker error in matrix multiplication in c using lapack library?

Tags: c, visual-c++, matrix-multiplication

I did Matrix multiplication using lapack library, I am getting an error like below. Can any one help me?

```
"error LNK2019: unresolved external symbol "void __cdecl dgemm(char,char,int *,int *,int *,double *,double *,int *,double *,int *,double *,double *,int *)" (?dgemm@@YAXDDPAH00PAN1010110@Z) referenced in function _main"
1>..\bin\matrixMultiplicationUsingLapack.exe : fatal error LNK1120: 1 unresolved externals
```

I post my code below

```
    # define matARowSize 2      // -- Matrix 1 number of rows
    # define matAColSize 2      // -- Matrix 1 number of cols
    # define matBRowSize 2      // -- Matrix 2 number of rows
    # define matBColSize 2      // -- Matrix 2 number of cols

using namespace std;


   void dgemm(char, char, int *, int *, int *, double *, double *, int *, double *, int *,        double *, double *, int *);

    int main()
    {
    double iMatrixA[matARowSize*matAColSize];   // -- Input matrix 1   {m x n}
    double iMatrixB[matBRowSize*matBColSize];   // -- Input matrix 2   {n x k}
    double iMatrixC[matARowSize*matBColSize];   // -- Output matrix    {m x n * n x     k = m x k}

    double alpha = 1.0f;
    double beta = 0.0f;

    int n = 2;

    iMatrixA[0] = 1;
    iMatrixA[1] = 1;
    iMatrixA[2] = 1;
    iMatrixA[3] = 1;

    iMatrixB[0] = 1;
    iMatrixB[1] = 1;
    iMatrixB[2] = 1;
    iMatrixB[3] = 1;

    //dgemm('N','N',&n,&n,&n,&alpha,iMatrixA,&n,iMatrixB,&n,&beta,iMatrixC,&n);

    dgemm('N','N',&n,&n,&n,&alpha,iMatrixA,&n,iMatrixB,&n,&beta,iMatrixC,&n);

    std::cin.get();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Wheres the definition of function "dgemm".

Comment: @vikky: Just in the code above

Answer (score 0):

This is a linker error due to unresolved reference. Can you please display your make file. Try changing your make file by putting the library name at the end. for example 
`gcc <program_name> lapack.a -o exec`

Answer (score 0):

The Linker Error is basically telling you that it cannot find your function `void dgemm(...)`.

If you look above your Main function, it seems like your `void dgemm(...)` function has no body.

The code that you put between the brackets represent the body of your function `{` `}`.

You should have something like this:

```
void dgemm(...)
{
    // Do stuff
}
```

That's why you are having the error.

Answer (score 0):

Linker error occur because compiler not find the function definition....

- Either you have to write definition of the function.
- Or if the function definition in library you must have to include the .lib file in the

  ProjectProperty-->Linker-->Input-->AdditionalDependencies-->"Add here.lib"